# Merging multiple cells in rhandsontable

Tags: list, shiny, merge, rhandsontable

I am trying to create a table using rhandsontable with several rows of merged cells (different cells in each row).

I am trying to achieve merging of the indicated cells in the screenshot below ...

[image]

I am able to successfully merge the first set of cells (row 11) but subsequent merges using a "list of lists" to specify the cells doesn't work. I have tried every permutation of the "list of lists" syntax that I can think of;

a reprex of the example is here ...

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

## Create the data set
DF = data.frame((Cycle = 1:13),
            `A` = as.numeric(""),
            `B` = as.numeric(""),
            `C` = as.numeric(""),
            `D` = as.numeric(""))

DF[11,1] = "Total"
DF[12,1] = ""
DF[13,1] = "Loss"

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$hotTable <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(DF,
                                     width = 1500, height = 350, rowHeaders = FALSE) %>%
                                     hot_cols(colWidths = c(100, 150, 150, 150, 150)) %>%
                                     hot_col(c(1,3:5), readOnly = TRUE) %>%
                                     hot_col(col = c(1:5), halign = "htCenter") %>%
                                     hot_col(col = c(2:4), format = "0.0000") %>%
                                     hot_col(col = 5, format = 0000) %>% 
                                     hot_table(mergeCells = list(list(row = 10, col = 2, rowspan = 1, colspan = 3),
                                                                 list(row = 11, col = 1, rowspan = 1, colspan = 5),
                                                                 list(row = 12, col = 3, rowspan = 1, colspan = 3)))})
    
  })


ui <- basicPage(mainPanel(rHandsontableOutput("hotTable")))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should change some parameters as follow:

```
mergeCells = list(list(row = 10, col = 2, rowspan = 1, colspan = 3),
                  list(row = 11, col = 0, rowspan = 1, colspan = 5),
                  list(row = 12, col = 2, rowspan = 1, colspan = 3))
```

so your desired *rhandsontable* would be produced as you want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Erfan - I didn't now the column numbers were zero filled.